# Rails: how to pass OR statement into current_page method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following code that denotes an active tab whenever the user is on a certain subpage, in this case the Users index view.

```
  <li class="<%='active' if current_page?(users_path) %>">
    <%= link_to 'Users',      users_path %></li>
```

I'd like it so that the tab is shown as "active" whenever the user is on any of the show, edit, OR index pages.

I tried something like this:

```
  <li class="<%='active' if current_page?(users_path || edit_user_path || user_path) %>">
    <%= link_to 'Users',      users_path %></li>
```

But only users_path is recognized.

What's the correct way to build an OR statement into the current_page method?

Answer (score 0):

that should be

```
<li class="<%='active' if current_page?(users_path) || current_page?(edit_user_path) || current_page?(user_path) %>">
```

this will be hard to maintain if you're doing this to a lot of pages.  You are better of using a gem for semantic navigation.

Comment: Thanks! Do you have any suggestions on a gem for semantic navigation?

Comment: we don't use one in our app but you can always go to rubygems and search http://rubygems.org/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&query=navigation

Answer (score 0):

This is some code I've used in previous apps.

```
def nav_item(copy, link)                             
  content_tag :li, class: nav_class(link) do         
    link_to copy, link                             
  end                                                
end

def nav_class(page)
  case page
  when :users     then 'active' if request.path.match(/^\/users/)
  when :projects  then 'active' if request.path.match(/^\/projects/)       
  else                                               
    nil                                              
  end                                                
end
```

The two helper methods above will render a link inside a `li` tag with `class="active"` if the route matches the current path.

Not on a UsersController action:

```
<%= nav_item('Users', :users) %>  #=> <li><a href="/users">Users</a></li>
```

On a UsersController action:

```
<%= nav_item('Users', :users) %>  #=> <li class="active"><a href="/users">Users</a></li>
```